# less command runs out of memory

Tags: less, gnu

When searching for string (no regex etc.) in large file `less filename` and `less -b 1 filename` quits or prints it cannot allocate memory. `top` shows less using roughly about 5% of memory before it dies (1 sec interval).

What other tool can I use that supports large files? The file has only 100 mb of logs.

```
$ less -V
less 458 (GNU regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

OS details:

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       15988
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          2048000
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 15988
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
$ cat /etc/*rele*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
```

Comment: What is your machine and OS ?

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with your memory and everything to do with the way `less` is written and how much space it allocates for its internal variables.

Anyway, `less` is really not designed for this, you should use a tool like `grep` instead:

```
grep yourQuery file
```

If you want to see the lines around your query (5 for example), run this:

```
grep -C 5 yourQuery file
```

If you have too many matches for that, you can pass the output to `less` and now you should be able to search through it:

```
grep -C 5 yourQuery file | less
```

Of course, if you want to do this manually, you can open the file in a text editor. Any serious editor like `vim` or `emacs` will be able to open and search through a 100MB file.

Comment: `vim` actually needs Control-c to show contents, not intuitive, but it can handle it. I was not aware of `grep -C` option - thanks.

Comment: @Rumca nothing about vim is intuitive (excellent, yes but not intuitive), just use your favorite editor.

Comment: Yes, I've opened huge files in `vi`/`emacs`. Not a pleasant experience... and the editor is even more likely to run out of memory than `less` (if yout think about it, the data structures to keep track of changes and allow changing the file are bound to be more complex and bulky than those required just to keep track of current position).

Comment: Apologies for a side question, does `less` load the entire file in memory? I also want to note that I use `vim` for this, and I really love vim as my go-to editor for almost everything (yes, I took a long time to 'grok' it). But it is what it is, not intuitive!

Comment: @0xc0de no, `less` does not. See `man less`: "Also, less does not have to read the entire input file  before  starting,  so  with  large  input files it starts up faster than text editors like  vi ".

Comment: So zless took my small 1GB ram AWS instance down! On file size: 100MB gzipped, 1.38GB uncompressed. I had to reboot it - too late for ctrl-c. `top` > `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` Fatal command `zless log.gz`, seek to end. Running less on the actual 1.38GB raw file is fine (as long as I do not display line numbers - ctrl-c that if you see it on a large file!). zless is actually a sh script which pipes gzip to less.

Answer (score 1):

You should strive to run less without line numbers as this is the usual case with large files, less -n .  I like to use case insensitive search as well, so it's always:  less -ni  wherever it's possible (busybox's default less does not support those command line options, for example).